# mvn -U doesn't appear to refresh parent poms

Tags: java, maven, nexus

Using Maven 3.8.x (not sure of the exact version).

I support the platform side of a large set of services that use a parent pom with an intranet artifact repository (nexus).  I often update artifacts in nexus and see them downloaded with "mvn -U" on the desktop and our CI servers.

Yesterday I had a situation where I had to update the latest release version (not snapshot) of our parent pom.  One of the changes was changing the version of Surefire.  I deployed that version to nexus and inspected the artifact in the index to verify the change was there. I verified with a local build that it's getting the new version. I then ran a CI build, but when Surefire ran, it was still using the old version of Surefire.  I tried this several times, but it's not getting the new version.

It almost seems like "mvn -U" doesn't do the same thing with parent poms that it does with other artifacts, but I can't find any documentation to that effect.

I'm going to proceed to purge the artifact from the local maven repos on the build nodes, but a different team has to do that.

Is there any reason to expect this behavior from "mvn -U"?  Would adding "-X" tell me anything useful?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you expect from `-U` if you are not using SNAPSHOT versions? With release versions, you build a new version each time you change something so there is no need to "update" an existing artifact.

Comment: Well, at least the top-level doc for "-U" is a little ambiguous. It says " -U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for missing
                                        releases and updated snapshots on
                                        remote repositories". So, it refers to snapshots, but also releases. In any case, what I'm seeing is that the artifact isn't being updated in the local maven repo.

Comment: I do not quite get what you are doing. Are you building a release version of a parent POM again, i.e. if there is a version 1.1.0 of the parent POM, you redeploy a different parent POM with the same version 1.1.0 instead of using the next version 1.2.0 or 1.1.1? Replacing a parent POM of version 1.1.0 with a different parent POM of version 1.1.0 is undefined behaviour and will cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: `mvn -U` does following: downloads snapshots, downloads latest releases **if version ranges are in use**, retries related downloads failed previously (i.e. resets `*.lastUpdated`)

Comment: Have you defined the verison of the surefire-plugin in your pom file or not? Or in your parent pom? Ah btw. have you change the version of your parent pom in your current project? Can you show some examples?

Comment: I am using version ranges for some things, but not for the parent pom reference, as you can't do that there. The previous download likely didn't fail. I have defined the surefire version in the parent pom, and I have not changed the version of the parent pom.

Comment: First you are wrong. You can define a version range for the parent version (I recommend to use most recent versions of Maven 3.8/3.9.X and recommend not to use version ranges at all) if you have defined the version of maven-surefire-plugin in your parent and use the same version of your parent in your project nothing will change the used version of maven-surefire-plugin. in your current project unless you change the version of your parent to use the more recent version of your parent which has defined the different version of maven-surefire-plugin...

Comment: Everything is working now, I understand what was happening here now. I had the release artifact purged from the build nodes and reran the build, and now the child build is getting the correct surefire version.

Comment: Hm.. that sounds strange... if the release artifact is already there it means it had been downloaded already. the question is why is it not taken into account from your own project? I would do further investigation what the real reason wa...

Comment: "why is it not taken into account from your own project"? I don't know what that means.